# Prevent evaluation of function result

Tags: hold

Forgive my ignorance, I'm new to Mathematica/the Wolfram Language.

I'm looking for a way to apply HoldForm or some equivalent to the result of a function, as well as its arguments.

For example, I would like to modify

```
Sort[Unevaluated[n+1+2]]]
```

so that it returns `1+2+n` rather than `3+n`.

Using `Trace` on this line reveals the following.

```
{Sort[n+1+2],1+2+n,3+n}
```

So it appears that my arguments are being passed in unevaluated, as I had hoped, but that the result is evaluated. How can I prevent this?

Edit:

I have found that using some version of Inactive doesn't quite suit my needs, at least on its face, because I would like to be able to convert the result to a string for export. From what I can tell:

```
ToString[HoldForm[1+2+n]]
```

returns `"1 + 2 + n"`, which is what I need.

However,

```
ToString[Inactive[Plus][1+2+n]]
```

or

```
ToString[Inactive[Plus] @@ Sort[{n, 1, 2}]]
```

returns a string with the `Inactive` wrapper.

Is there a way to use `HoldForm` rather than `Inactive`? Or is there a way to make an inactive expression convert to a string without the wrapper?

Comment: `Inactive[Plus] @@ Sort[{n, 1, 2}]`

Comment: Thanks for the comment, @Bob Hanlon. I have found that Inactive[Plus] doesn't quite suit my needs. I have modified my question to add clarification.

Comment: `ToString[Plus @@ (ToString /@ Sort[{n, 1, 2}])]`

Comment: You can also circumvent the issue of `Inactive[Plus]` by replacing it afterwards: `Inactive[Plus] @@ Sort[{n, 1, 2}] /. 
 Inactive[Plus][a__] :> HoldForm[Plus[a]]`

Comment: Do you care about preventing evaluation of `n` or only about `1`/`2` not being added up. What is really the input here?

Comment: So, any feedback?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on exactly what you are trying to achieve, you could replace `Plus` with, for example, `CirclePlus`

```
Sort[n⊕1⊕2]
(* 1⊕2⊕n *)
```